# Tangent Line at Level Curve

Tags: derivatives

Let $z: \Bbb R\times \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$

$z = f(x,y)$ be differentiable function, whose diretive derivative at $(a,b)$ is $3$ following the direction of $(1, 1)$ and $-2$ following the direction of $(1,-2)$.

Then the tangent curve at (a,b) which is on level curve, which includes $(a,b)$ is,

Then directive derivative would be 5/3 following the direction of (0,1), and 4/3 following the direction of (1,0).

Then the tangent line would be $\frac{4}{3}(x-a)+\frac{5}{3}(y-b) = 0$ and $z = f(a,b)$

Is it correct?

Comment: that's a plane not a line

Comment: @sakethmalyala edited OP.

Comment: @amd edited thx